# Intellij idea error highlighting

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to mark some texts in intellij editor as error by underlining with read colour in my plugin using carret position. is there any way to do it. already i can get position and text which i need to mark as error from ide editor. is this possible please help me.

Comment: Error highlighting can be done using http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/annotator.html for more information.
public class ScalaAnnotator implements Annotator {    public void annotate(@NotNull final PsiElement element, @NotNull AnnotationHolder holder) {parameter PsiElement contains all details of editor  and by AnnotationHolder you can mark as error or change colour using  TextRange range = new TextRange(1,9)
 Annotation annotation = holder.createInfoAnnotation(range, null);
annotation.setTextAttributes(DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.STATIC_FIELD);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error highlighting can be done using http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/annotator.html
for more information.

```
    public class ScalaAnnotator implements Annotator {
       @Override
     public void annotate(@NotNull final PsiElement element, @NotNull AnnotationHolder holder) {
```

parameter PsiElement contains all details of editor  and by AnnotationHolder you can mark as error or change colour using

```
                TextRange range = new TextRange(element2.getTextRange().getStartOffset(),
                        element2.getTextRange().getEndOffset());
                Annotation annotation = holder.createInfoAnnotation(range, null);
                annotation.setTextAttributes(DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.STATIC_FIELD);
```